# Xamarin PushAsync Animation (Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation

I've got a question regarding the default animation of a PushAsync Navigation call on Xamarin.

All Android Apps seem to have a default animation for a new page, which is the new page sliding in from the right to the left (also shifting the old page a little bit to the left while being overlapped). You can see this e.g. on WhatsApp, when you tap on a chat to open the chat page.

On Xamarin however, the new page doesn't slide in on Android, instead, it kind of fades in. I tried the animation parameter on PushAsync (false and true) but nothing really changes.

So my question is: How do I set up new pages to slide in from the right to the left in Xamarin?

Kind regards

Comment: "Most" Android apps are using multiple activities (and|or fragments) to handle content changes and you can control the enter/exit animation translations at the activity level (https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity) while Forms using a "single" activity (w/ fragments for some elements) for the entire Forms' application and does not support "Page" level animations by default. There are some blog posts about creating custom Page renderers to simulate this style of enter/exit transitions, just google/bing it.

Comment: You can try  https://github.com/AlexandrNikulin/AnimationNavigationPage

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the right instruction for navigation provided by [Xamarin here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical), then what you are seeing is the native behavior of Android.

However if you want to force a different behavior, there are NuGet packages that will help you do this that you can add to your solution. But you could also just put in the underlying code so you can override the default behavior, as you can see in the [example here](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions/).

Comment: I am doing just that. However, the default behavior seems to be the new page shifting on top of the current page. I want to to achieve that effect. Might be a matter of an activity change or something